# form does not submit after file upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view where a user can edit his profile information. Here are input text fields and he can also add a profile image. To do this i did the following using ASP .net MVC3 with razor as follows:

In the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SettingsWizard", "Business", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="SettingsForm" }))
        { 

            @Html.Partial("_UsrConfiguration", Model)

            @Html.Partial("_OtherPartialView")

            @Html.Partial("_OtherPartialViewTwo")


            <p class="textAlignRight">
                <input type="submit" class="bb-140" id="button7" value="Save"/>
    </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        }
```

In the _UsrConfiguration partial view to handle the images:

```
<div class="floatRight" >
    <a onclick="javascript:opendialogbox('imageLoad2');" style="cursor: pointer">Foto</a>
    <img src="../../Content/themes/base/images/icons/zoom.png" width="16" height="16" id="imgThumbnail2" alt="foto" />
    <input type="file" name="imageLoad2" accept="image/*" id="imageLoad2" onchange="ChangeProfileImage()" hidden="hidden" />
</div>
```

With these scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeProfileImage() {
        var ext = document.getElementById('imageLoad2').value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
        switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'bmp':
            case 'png':
            case 'gif':
            case 'jpeg':
                {
                    var myform = document.createElement("form");
                    myform.style.display = "none";
                    myform.action = "/ImagePreview/ProfileImageSubmit";
                    myform.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
                    myform.method = "post";
                    var imageLoad;
                    var imageLoadParent;
                    var is_chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
                    if (is_chrome && document.getElementById('imageLoad2').value == '')
                        return; //Chrome bug onchange cancel
                    if (document.all || is_chrome) {//IE
                        imageLoad = document.getElementById('imageLoad2');
                        imageLoadParent = document.getElementById('imageLoad2').parentNode;
                        myform.appendChild(imageLoad);
                        document.body.appendChild(myform);
                    }
                    else {//FF
                        imageLoad = document.getElementById('imageLoad2').cloneNode(true);
                        myform.appendChild(imageLoad);
                        document.body.appendChild(myform);
                    }
                    $(myform).ajaxSubmit({ success:
                        function (responseText) {
                            var d = new Date();
                            $("#imgThumbnail2")[0].src = "/ImagePreview/ProfileImageLoad?a=" + d.getMilliseconds();
                            if (document.all || is_chrome)//IE
                                imageLoadParent.appendChild(myform.firstChild);
                            else//FF                     
                                document.body.removeChild(myform);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            default:
                alert('File type error…');
        }

    }
</script>
```

On the controller side to handle the images:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ProfileImageSubmit(int? id)
{
Session["ContentLength"] = Request.Files[0].ContentLength;
        Session["ContentType"] = Request.Files[0].ContentType;
        byte[] b = new byte[Request.Files[0].ContentLength]; 
        Request.Files[0].InputStream.Read(b, 0, Request.Files[0].ContentLength); 
        //DB saving logic and persist data with…
    repo.Save();

        return Content(Request.Files[0].ContentType + ";" + Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
}

public ActionResult ProfileImageLoad(int? id)
{

    TCustomer usr = new TCustomer();
        usr = repo.load(User.Identity.Name);
byte[] b = usr.ContactPhoto; 
        string type = (string)Session["ContentType"];
    Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = type;
        Response.BinaryWrite(b);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        Session["ContentLength"] = null;
        Session["ContentType"] = null; 
        return Content("");
}
```

This works fine. Problem is that if a user adds an image to his profile, then the

```
<input type="submit" class="bb-140" id="button7" value="Save"/>
```

button does not do anything. But if the user edits his profile without adding an image the input button submits the way it should. I tried binding the input's click function using

```
$(document).on('click','#button7',function(e){
  $("#SettingsForm").submit();
});
```

but the problem persisted...
I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are handling the form for the image upload the way you are.  You can just have two forms in your view.  We are doing that with no problems.  Just make sure each form contains all the elements it needs data from.  To use one element in both forms, make a hidden input to mirror the other, and use jQuery to keep the values up to date.

Hmmm...starting to see the issue.  The way you have things layed out, the second form I suggested would be nested inside the original form.  I have a place where I have a workaround where I have several submit buttons on the same form.  The buttons look like this :

```
    <input type="submit" value=" Save Changes " name="submitButton" />
```

Then in my action, I use this signature :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessForm(FormCollection collection)
```

and find out what button was clicked with :

```
    string submitCommand = collection["submitButton"];
```

Then, I just have a switch(submitCommand) block, where I perform the appropriate actions for the button.  In your case, you would have to make the action signature :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessForm(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

so that you would have the file object to save when the save picture button was clicked.  I can't guarantee that this will work, but I'm fairly sure.

If it does not, then the ugly workaround is to get the form for uploading the picture seperated from the form for updating the profile.  That won't be pretty...although you may be able to get it done by putting the image form in a dialog (outside of the main from) and opening it with jQuery dialog.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The reason the image is handled this way is becuase i need to to reload dynamically on the page after the user selects it (a preview). When i tried doing what you suggested both forms would be submitted when i tried to handle the image.

Comment: if you could show me a simple example where i could preview an image beside the name label (for example) of the user data form to be submitted i would greatly appreciate it. Sorry if I'm takeing up too much of your time.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. Let me try it and let you know. Thanks again